# JMS encoded message selector not matching when using special characters

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, correlation, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I have 2 applications (client and server) using a request-reply pattern.

The client sends a request to the server the message ID is set to something like this: `ID=Hostname-52991-1357677886768-3:1:2:1:1`.

Now the client has to listen to a message with a correlation ID set to the same value. Since the value contains special characters (:) I have to encode the value (using UTF-8).

> Sets the JMS Selector, which is an SQL 92 predicate that is used to filter messages within the broker. You may have to encode special characters such as = as %3D

So the selector should look like `JMSCorrelationID='ID=Hostname-52991-1357677886768-3:1:2:1:1'` and the encoded selector should look like `JMSCorrelationID='ID%3AHostname-52991-1357677886768-3%3A1%3A2%3A1%3A1'` I guess.

I have struggled for a couple of hours now and searched and read everything I could find but I cannot get this thing to work and it's driving me nuts.

Using only ASCII characters like `abcd` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JMS selector selector is being HTML encoded which will not work with the underlying system(as it will never match a message). The expression JMSCorrelationID='ID=Hostname-52991-1357677886768-3:1:2:1:1' should work as is.

Comment: Weird... I tried it again today, and it worked, indeed without encoding. I initially got `InvalidSelectorException`s with nested `TokenMgrError`s with some message like `Lexical error at line 1, column ?.  Encountered: ' after :`. So that's an easy 50 for you I guess. ;-)